# How to make related item to the carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I have a multi items carousels and whenever it goes to another item I want to change the content.[image]

As you see in the picture in the carousel, "evde leziz" is on and the bottom (marked with yellow) is related to the carousel. For the carousel, I am using lightslider library (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/)

And here is my basic html:

```
<div class="start__carousel">
          <ul id="lightSlider">
            <li>
              <img src="./assets/img/meal1.jpg" />
              <div class="carousel__title">Leziz Detox</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="./assets/img/meal3.jpg" />
              <div class="carousel__title">Leziz Classic</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="./assets/img/meal2.jpg" />
              <div class="carousel__title">Leziz Protein</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

And also the bottom part:

```
<section class="delicious">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <div class="left">
                <div class="title">Leziz Classic</div>
                <div>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <div class="right">
                <div class="image__area">
                  <img src="./assets/img/delicious.jpg" alt="Meal" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I know it is a little bit too much, maybe you may need to see more but if you can help me with it, I would be really glad.

Thanks...

Comment: you need to maintain some sort of relationship between carousel slide and the content below. I have not used this carousel but looking at documentation that you have provided there are certain events e.g. `onBeforeNextSlide` or `onBeforePrevSlide` that I believe you can make use of, given that you have some defined relationship between the slide and content that you want to change based on slide.  Maintaining the relationship depends if it's a static or dynamic page, So, based on selected slide you can retrieve relevant data from DB/API or if static you can show/hide relevant divs/containers

Comment: So what I am trying to do is when it is meal1, I want to show <section class="delicious"></section> And if it is meal2, I want to show <section class="delicious2"></section>

Comment: yeah need to have some mapping e.g. if it's a static site, you can create a JS object or something that specifies the relationships e.g. `var mappings = {"id-of-carousel-slide": "bottom-content-section-id"}`, then use this object to determine the section to show based on current carousel slide

Comment: I didnt understand this part: then use this object to determine the section to show based on current carousel slide

Comment: JS object is essentially a collection of `key : value` pair, where keys should be exactly the carousel slide ids and value should be the section ids that you need to show for each slide. In this way, once you know the active slide id, you can iterate through JS object and get the value (section id) where key = current slide's id . showing/hiding the section when you have the section id (value from JS object) is just the matter of using built in jquery functions. you can easily find code samples which let you iterate through JS object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your question, it was really challenging
I did this with JavaScript (without using lightslider library).

`Demo here:` https://jsfiddle.net/M_Ali2002/df4wkgop/9/